# Random windows WHEA bluescreen: Involves something else running, not sure how to diagnose

Tags: windows-10, steam, opengl, rendering

So I will run a game [both: Epic Battle Simulator II, and Cyberpunk MMLXXVII]

- On a naked windows install, before i install Steam, or anything ("offline* install*")
  using bittorrent... no problem.

But on my set windows... WHEA
and not even always.
But always RIGHT at the start of execution. (never like...minutes later which would indicate some bad hardware)

looking for suggestions on diagnosing this.
(It feels like it has something to do with 3D Engine rendering in backround)

Comment: WHEA is an uncorrectable error is normally a Driver problem. Update ALL drivers for your machine (use the Manufacturer's Driver Update App)

Comment: Yes, I know what WHEA means. However "driver errors" are not always that cut-and-dry

Comment: I have seen WHEA errors before and driver update (especially BIOS and Video) are very important to do.

Comment: So I did just tell you @john that i have tested this on a naked install, and it worked fine. Perhaps I should edit my post to clarify?

Comment: Look for hardware errors using the Manufacturer’s Hardware Diagnostic App. Also even though the apps you name are not running, it can still be a driver issue

Comment: Do you have a crash dump file?  The info here: `https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/bug-check-0x124---whea-uncorrectable-error`  tells you to run for example !errrec with the address of param 2.